# Show name of saved file in Upload Field using kartik form in Yii2

Tags: yii2, kartik-v

I have an application built using Yii2 framework, and the app has a form using **kartik\form\ActiveForm**, this is some line in my _form.php. In that form, user should upload a file, and submit it. After that form successfully saved, the user trying to update the data, but the form didn't show the saved uploaded file. Like this
[image]

I need to show the saved file name in that upload field. How do I can do it?
This is my code in _form.php

```
 <?=
$form->field($model, 'buktiNpwp')->widget(FileInput::classname(), [  
    'options' => [
        'multiple' => false,
        'accept' => 'img/*', 'doc/*', 'file/*',
        'class' => 'optionvalue-img',
        'placeholder' => 'maximum size is 2 MB',            
    ],
    'pluginOptions' => [
        'allowedFileExtensions' => ['jpg', 'gif', 'png', 'jpeg'],
        'maxFileSize' => 2048, //membatasi size file upload
        'layoutTemplates' => ['footer' => 'Maximum size is 2 MB'],
        'browseLabel' => 'Browse (2MB)',
        'showPreview' => false,
        'showCaption' => true,
        'showRemove' => true,
        'showUpload' => false,
    ]
]);
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To save images do this in your controller. Hope that will work

```
$model = new YourModel();

$files = UploadedFile::getInstances($model, 'name');
foreach($files as $file){
   $path = 'somepath';
   $file->saveAs($path);
}
```

on update controller you can do

```
$images_old = \common\models\YourModel::find()->where(['=', 'some_id', $model->id])->all();

if ($images_old) {
            foreach ($images_old as $image) {
                $baseurl = \Yii::$app->request->BaseUrl;
                $image_url = $baseurl . '/uploads/' . $image->thumbnail;
                $all_images[] = Html::img("$image_url", ['class' => 'file-preview-image']);
                $obj = (object) array('caption' => '', 'url' => $baseurl . '/some-path/delete-image', 'key' => $image->id);
                $all_images_preview[] = $obj;
            }
        }
```

Now send the $all_images_preview and $all_images to your view file and show it like

```
$form->field($images, 'name[]')->widget(FileInput::classname(), [
            'options' => ['accept' => 'image/*', 'multiple' => true],
            'pluginOptions' => [
                'previewFileType' => 'image',
                'allowedFileExtensions' => ['jpg', 'gif', 'png', 'bmp','jpeg'],
                'showUpload' => true,
                'initialPreview' => $all_images,
                'initialPreviewConfig'=>$all_images_preview,
                'overwriteInitial' => false,
                'showRemove' => true,
                'showPreview' => true,
                'uploadUrl' => Url::to(['cases/upload']),
                //'onRemove'=>''

            ],
        ]);
```

Comment: I've successfully get the image name, but it failed when show in view.

Comment: What error do you get? Check for console errors with inspect element.

Answer (score 0):

In your controller class and just `actionUpload` define upload file directory path, because `UploadedFile` model save a file in absolute physical path. If you need, can necessary verify post variable use `$_FILES`. The method `saveAs` need complete absolute file path and file name. Use slash or backslash according to its SO to best results.